# SQL Server 2008 - Remove the parentheses and anything between

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a hard time to figure out how to remove the parentheses and anything inside it, plus the space in front.  I tried the combination of CharIndex, Substring, and LEFT, but could not get it work correctly.

Here is the example.  Let's say I have a very simple table "ContactName" and a column "DisplayName"

Query would be "Select DisplayName FROM ContactName".

In the ContactName table, the data looks like this:

```
Joe Blow (joe.blow@yahoo.com)
John Deep (jdeep@gmail.com)
(Tim.King@gmail.com) King, Timothy
Richard Harris
Wang, Justin
```

What I would like to do is removing anything with the parenthesis including the space in front of it if any.  For example, "Joe Blow (joe.blow@yahoo.com)" will become "Joe Blow" with NO space, not "Joe Blow ".  Also, "(Tim.King@gmail.com) King, Timothy" will become "King, Timothy"

Example of the result would be like this, and NO trailing spaces after the name.

```
Joe Blow
John Deep
King, Timothy
Richard Harris
Wang, Justin
```

Maybe I  need some kind of RegEx to accomplish this.  Please help.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove all characters between `(` and `)` in the string (if they are present), you can use `stuff` and then a combination of `ltrim` and `rtrim` to remove all the trailing and leading spaces.

```
case when charindex('(',displayname) > 0 and charindex(')',displayname) > 0 
     then rtrim(ltrim(stuff(displayname,charindex('(',displayname),charindex(')',displayname),'')))
else displayname end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one rather brute force way that works when the parentheses are either at the beginning or end:

```
select (case when displayname like '(%'
             then stuff(displayname, 1, charindex(') ', displayname + ') '), '')
             when displayname like '%)'
             then left(displayname, charindex(' (', displayname + ' ('))
             else displayname
        end)
```

Not an idea solution, but SQL Server doesn't have great support for strings.

Comment: why not `stuff(displayname,charindex('('),charindex(')'),'')` ?

Comment: Wow, Thank you for a quick response.  The result is still have the trailing space for "Joe Blow " and the beginning space for " King, Timothy", is there any trick to remove it in the query you provided?

Comment: select ltrim(rtrim(case.... end))) will remove beginning & trailing spaces

Comment: @Hogan . . . The `stuff()` is when the beginning of the line starts with the parentheses.  In that case, you need to fast forward to the end of the parentheses.

Comment: but my code handles that case too -- I don't understand why it needs special handling.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (DisplayName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES ('Joe Blow (joe.blow@yahoo.com)'),
       ('John Deep (jdeep@gmail.com)'),
       ('(Tim.King@gmail.com) King, Timothy'),
       ('Richard Harris'),
       ('Wang, Justin')

SELECT RTRIM(
        LTRIM(
            REPLACE(DisplayName,
                    SUBSTRING(  DisplayName,
                                CHARINDEX('(',DisplayName,1),
                                ((CHARINDEX(')',DisplayName, 1)) - (CHARINDEX('(',DisplayName,1))+1)
                              ),
                    '')
             )
        )
FROM @Table
```